# Image not showing in View (Laravel Blade file)

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

Image is present at the directory:
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\ecommerce\public\upload\products\thumbnail > 1743108095211357.jpg

It perfectly opens when i type the URL
http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/products/thumbnail/1743108095211357.jpg

But when i open the view page it does not display there, here is code i am using to display it:

```
<td><img src="{{ asset('/'.$item->product_thumbnail) }}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" alt=""></td>
```

when the page opens in browser and by inspecting the page i have found that the URL it opens in browser is

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/products/thumbnail1743108095211357.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" alt="">
```

there is no '/' between thumbnail folder and image name how can i fix this? Thanks!

Also

```
<td><img src="{{ asset($item->product_thumbnail) }}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" alt=""></td>
```

gives same error, no forward slash between folder and file name.

Comment: What does `$item->product_thumbnail` contain, the filename only or a path?

Comment: @brombeer Im using @foreach($products as $item) and products is the table in my database and product_thumbnail is the column field of said table. It contains url to file like in this case:  upload/products/thumbnail1743108095211357.jpg

Comment: Make sure it is `thumbnail1743108095211357.jpg` or `thumbnail/1743108095211357.jpg` in database?

Comment: Its: thumbnail1743108095211357.jpg

Comment: It seems that you didn't save it with proper path like you said no forward slash between folder and file name.

Comment: oops, thanks guys, as i am new to Laravel, i dont remember where did i set this location can you point to where i check to update this?

Comment: Thankyou guys. For starters like me it was fixed by going to Controller and search there your location then add forward slash to path then you also need to update locations in database of existing image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it like this.

**Controller**

```
Products::create([
    'product_thumbnail' => 'upload/products/thumbnail/'. $fileName
]);
```